# How to reveal the admin password when logged in with one time login link?

Tags: drush, users

I just started on a project and there is a prod and dev server. I have access to the dev server and I'm able to do a force login via 'drush uli admin' but I do not have access to the prod server to do the same thing. Is there a way to reveal the admin password on the dev drupal when logged in as admin?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: no.

A Drupal password is saved to the database after getting hashed, and the hash is not reversible in any sense that you're hoping for.

An alternative solution would be to try to reset the password to something you know.  Drupal has [a description of an SQL approach](https://www.drupal.org/node/1023428) if you can't use the "reset password" function.

If you don't have command line access you can [try using a PHP method to reset it](https://www.drupal.org/node/1556488).  However, that is really a last resort kind of situation because of the security implications.  **Super last resort.**

Answer (score 0):

You could install the [AES module](https://www.drupal.org/project/aes). It might give you that ability.

Comment: to late, it won't help him with current password. And of course I think it's bad idea for it to be possible in the first place.